# Why does Cobertura report 0% coverage when run through the Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, code-coverage, cobertura

(There are a tonne of these questions, but all the ones I can find relate to Maven. Before you suggest this one is a duplicate, please understand that this doesn't relate to Maven in any way.)

I am using [Cobertura](http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/) within Eclipse to determine my percentage of code covered by my JUnit tests. All 99 of my unit tests run successfully, both within and outside of Cobertura, but Cobertura reports back that they have covered 0% of my code.

I :

- am running Cobertura through the Eclipse plugin
- am using Java 6, specifically OpenJDK-AMD64 on Ubuntu
- have ensured that the unit tests *do* cover some sections of my code
- have ensured that Cobertura is running all my test folder on all of my src folder
- have tried to clean and rebuild

Why does Cobertura report 0%?

Comment: I haven't solved this issue - but I got around it by sticking my reports into an Ant file...

Comment: Does it work if you run it through Maven's `cobertura:cobertura` goal?

Comment: @Joe I'm not using Maven but since it works with Ant I would assume so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this was a problem for me because I was compiling my source files without line numbers. If this is your problem, you will see

```
[cobertura-instrument] WARN visitEnd, No line number information found for class com.x.y.z.A.
Perhaps you need to compile with debug=true?
```

To solve this, add `debug="true" debuglevel="vars,lines,source"` to your `javac` command.

See also:

http://meera-subbarao.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/cobertura-instrument-warn-visitend-no.html

[How to remove specific Cobertura warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087948/how-to-remove-specific-cobertura-warning)